# Cannot launch Gnome terminal on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome-terminal

I was trying to downgrade my latest gnome-terminal to version 3.6.2 as given in

[Upgrade to 15.04: What happened to my gnome-terminal tabs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613465/upgrade-to-15-04-what-happened-to-my-gnome-terminal-tabs)

But after restart, the terminal won't launch. When I try to install the same version otherwise from X term, it notifies me of the error:

```
**The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gnome-terminal : Depends: libvte-2.90-9 (>= 1:0.34.9) but it is not installable**
```

Can someone help?

Comment: An attempt to launch it from X-term says:



`error while loading shared libraries: libvte-2.90.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Never mind @inferrna

Your noob solution didn't work for me as I fugured downgrading was a bad option. Anyways I could get the data files for the gnome-terminal named <gnome-terminal-data_3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb> and after installing it my terminal runs smooth and fine now.

I decided to downgrade it because the latest terminal doesn't have the features like renaming a tab or saving the tabs etc.

Comment: So, is this solved? I was going to  suggest doing `sudo dpkg -r gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data && sudo apt install gnome-terminal` in a TTY. This will at least leave you with a working terminal.

Comment: Yes it did finally thanks. But I couldn't get this option of "terminal-data". Thanks for replying though. :)

Comment: So, did you successfully downgrade terminal to 3.6.2 ?

Comment: No the downgrade didn't work as I wrote earlier. I happy with the upgraded one and it did it by installing the new data files